# "Error executing the insertHtml command" message in cleditor when inserting html in "View Source" mode

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, cleditor

I've searched for the solution for this everywhere and have not found an answer, so you're my last hope, Stackoverflow...

With regard to cleditor, does anybody know how to make the "inserthtml" command in "View Source" mode work?

Currently, I have a method attached to a button's onclick handler that inserts a string into the cleditor's textarea:

```
editor.focus();
setTimeout(function() { editor.execCommand('inserthtml', stringToInsert); }, 0);
```

The above works fine in the normal Rich Text mode but if you try to execute it while in **View Source** mode, the following will happen:

- In Firefox, it pops up a little message that says "Error executing
  the inserthtml command."
- In Chrome, it fails silently
- In IE:

  - If the textarea was empty, I hit a breakpoint in Visual Studio at "y(a).pasteHTML(c)" in what looks like jquery.cleditor.min.js, with the following message, "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unspecified error."
  - If the textarea already contained text, I hit a breakpoint at "a.range[0].select()" in the same file with the following message, "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Could not complete the operation due to error 800a025e."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi i think it is very simmilar problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215426/cleditor-minor-plugin-error/9215978#9215978)

i assume that code pasted by you is executed in button click function 
at the end of this function just add

return false;

add sopmething like that:

function someClick(e, data) {

```
    // Get the editor
    var editor = data.editor;

   editor.focus();
   setTimeout(function() { editor.execCommand('inserthtml', stringToInsert); }, 0);

   return false;
```

}

edit:

yep you are right it is not so easy : when yo are in normal mode your text area is actualy iframe when you are in source mode your textarea is again becomeing textarea so to edit data inside you can get it by

```
$('#mytextarea').val()
```

if you want to append something at the end you can use :

```
setTimeout(function() {$('#mytextarea').val($('#mytextarea').val()+'aaaaa') }, 3000);
```

if you want to insert at current ursor cosition this should help : [Cursor position in a textarea (character index, not x/y coordinates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891444/how-can-i-get-cursor-position-in-a-textarea)

Comment: First of all, thank you for the reply.  If only it were that easy!  I've come across that solution before but it doesn't work - at least not for me.

Comment: if happy with my answer accept it +1 and someone else might use it in the future .

Comment: Thank you so much for you help!  The crucial info I needed was this:

_when yo are in normal mode your text area is actualy iframe when you are in source mode your textarea is again becomeing textarea_

If anyone else is struggling with this, this is how I solved it:
`editor.focus();

if (!editor.sourceMode()) {
   setTimeout(function() { editor.execCommand('inserthtml', stringToInsert); }, 0);
} else {
    setTimeout(function() { insertAtCursor($("#myTextArea").get(0), stringToInsert); }, 0);
}`

You need to make the insertAtCursor() method, of course.  I apologise if the formatting is messy.