# forced_root_block option in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, contenteditable

I am trying to implement a custom WYSIWYG editor using a `contenteditable` `<div>`.

One of the major issues I am facing is the inconsistent way browsers handle <kbd>ENTER</kbd> keystroke (linebreaks). Chrome inserts `<div>`, Firefox inserts `<br>` and IE inserts `<p>`. I was taking a look at TinyMCE and it has a configuration option called `forced_root_block`. Setting `forced_root_block` to `div` actually works across all major browser. Does someone know how `forced_root_block` option in TinyMCE is able to achieve it across browsers ?

Answer (score 2):

In the tinymce  source (/tiny_mce/classs/dom/DomParser.js) you will find the following:

```
rootBlockName = "forced_root_block" in args ? args.forced_root_block : settings.forced_root_block;

        whiteSpaceElements = schema.getWhiteSpaceElements();
        startWhiteSpaceRegExp = /^[ \t\r\n]+/;
        endWhiteSpaceRegExp = /[ \t\r\n]+$/;
        allWhiteSpaceRegExp = /[ \t\r\n]+/g;

        function addRootBlocks() {
            var node = rootNode.firstChild, next, rootBlockNode;

            while (node) {
                next = node.next;

                if (node.type == 3 || (node.type == 1 && node.name !== 'p' && !blockElements[node.name] && !node.attr('data-mce-type'))) {
                    if (!rootBlockNode) {
                        // Create a new root block element
                        rootBlockNode = createNode(rootBlockName, 1);
                        rootNode.insert(rootBlockNode, node);
                        rootBlockNode.append(node);
                    } else
                        rootBlockNode.append(node);
                } else {
                    rootBlockNode = null;
                }

                node = next;
            };
        };
```

This obviously takes care of creating root block elements.
I am 99% sure that tinymce handles the 'ENTER' keystroke itself and stops the propagation/ default browser command.

Comment: Yesm you are correct. I had a deeper look at tinymce source code. They have a class called 'EnterKey.js'. The main function in this class is 'handleEnterKey'. Tinymce traps the